Minimum number of weighings
Akbar has four golden crowns that he can wear. He does not know their exact weight but knows that all of them are an integral number of grams. Birbal has a balance that displays the difference of weights on the left and right pan but it is faulty. It may make a mistake of 1 gram either way in at most one weighing. Can you help Birbal to calculate the exact weight of these crowns? You need to do it in a minimum number of moves.
Here's what I've done
We can definitely do this in at most 7 weighings, lets say $x, y, z, w$ are the integer weights of the 4 crowns,
We compute, $w_1 = x-y$, $w_2 = y-z$, $w_3= x-z$, $w_4 = z-w$, $w_5=x-w$, $w_6 = w$
Note : I've introduced some redundancies to check whether there has been mistake in measuring weights before.
Now, check whether $w_1 + w_2 = w_3$, if this equation holds then there is no mistake in first three weighing otherwise of there is a mistake in one of the weighings then you'll need to measure quantity $w_1, w_2$ again, then you can measure $w_3, w_4, w_6$ without any worry and compute $x, y, z, w$.
In case there is no mistake in first three weighings, no you measure the next three and again check $w_3+w_4=w_5$.
If equal then only possible mistake can happen in measuring $w_6$, so measure it twice. Otherwise, only mistake is in $w_4$ or $w_5$, we only measure $w_4$ again (as $w_5$ is redundant) and then you measure $w_6$
As you see worst case is 7 weighings.
And for the lower bound you can imagine that you'll need 4 equations to solve for $x, y, z, w$ and at least one equation to check for a mistake.
My question is : Is it possible to do this exercise in 5 or 6 weighing ? and In case minimum is 7, how do I prove it ?
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Maybe I don't understand the rules.  Suppose the scale systematically adds $1$ to any weighing that has the $x$ crown on it, but otherwise measures everything correctly.  How could that ever be detected?

@lulu quoting from the problem statement "It may make a mistake of 1 gram either way in at most one weighing"

I can do it in four weighings.  As you do, let the crown weights be $x,y,z,w$ and $t=x+y+z+w$.  Our four weighings are:

 $$a=x+y+z-w=t-2w\\b=y+z+w-x=t-2x\\c=z+w+x-y=t-2y\\d=w+x+y-z=t-2z$$

To make use of the data

  We note that $a+b+c+d$ should be twice the total weight.  If one of the readings is in error the sum will be odd, not even.  If the sum is even, all the readings are good and we can just solve the system for the weights.  The four readings should have the same parity, so we can identify the incorrect one.  To get the sign of the error, we should have $a+b+c-d=4z$ so we use the sign that makes the sum be a multiple of $4$.  Once we have corrected the error we can solve the system.


thanks, it was a very nice and clean solution
